# memory allocation at instantiation time?

Tags: java, memory

how much memory get allocated(individually) for "code block-1,code block-2,code block-3,code block-4 when they are instantiated.what's the memory size of all instantiated object in heap.

```
code block-1 public class TestClass1 {}
code block-2 
        public class TestClass2 
           {
           String a=null;
           String b=null;
           }
code block-3 
         public class TestClass3 
          {
           String ab="mkmmmkkm";
           String bc="bbbbbbbkjbkbk";
          }
code block-4
          public class PerformanceTest
           {
             TestClass1 t1=new TestClass1();
             TestClass2 t2=new TestClass2();
             TestClass3 t3=new TestClass3();
            }
```

Comment: What do you think? Please demonstrate minimal understanding of what's asked.

Comment: i am learning about heap memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

`Class` is blue print of `object`, when you create object in memory at that time memory is allocated as per your `attribute` and `method` definition. for more information refer [link](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/kb/sizes.jsp)

`Java Profiler` is good tool, It will display memory allocation details. [refer this](http://eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html) if you are using eclipse.